# Does the "new" Facebook Marketplace have a listing API?

Tags: facebook

Facebook recently launched a slightly better, and certainly more prominent, Marketplace to sell goods locally.  Is there an API for adding listings or does anyone know if there will be an API?

Comment: No there is no API for it yet

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: still no API???

Comment: Yes there is an API, see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

I doubt they will have an API for the Marketplace as it is designed as a person to person local marketplace, rather than a business to person marketplace. However, it would not be hard to build your own bot to post ads using something like nightmare.js. I looked into this a few months back and it took me about 2 hours to create a minimal bot that could post a basic ad. Could share the code with you if you want.

If you're not familiar with Javascript/Node.js, you could build it using any web scraper but Nightmare.js makes it really easy.

Comment: Thank you for the offer, but I have to pass--I've since lost interest.  It's probably a lot easier now, but when Marketplace first debuted, it was a mobile-only interface, which made it impossible for me for auto post.  Again, thanks! However, I think you have a taker below for the code sharing.

Comment: @John, it would be really awesome to get some sample code that you made to post an ad.

Comment: @Gerneio, Unfortunately, I didn't save the code or add it to Git :facepalm:. It was more of a test to see if it was possible. I am rebuilding it though and using it as a plugin for our desktop Craigslist posting software built on Electron. As soon as it is complete, I'll share the repo with you. :)

Comment: Awesome, much appreciated!

Comment: @JohnWalz We created a system that holds Car Dealer's inventory. From there, we have a section named Marketplace where dealers can set criteria that must be met before their vehicles can be shown in the "suggested list" column. Vehicles that lands in the "suggested list" column must have appropriate images selected in order to move along to the "awaiting approval" column.Vehicles that land here must be approved by the Dealer admin. Once he approves them, the next step would be to post them to Facebook Market Place with a click of a button. We are now working on the api section. How did you do?

Comment: @JohnWalz Hi, Do you have the code? I searched a lot but couldn't able to find the exact API and code. If you have a code please share with me.

Answer (score 5):

**Update** : You can now request your business to get listed on facebook marketplace. 
**Documentation** : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/shops-api.
**Form for Application** : https://www.facebook.com/shops-api-alpha/.

Please note, this is a limited alpha so only select partners will be eligible for access to the API.

Comment: FYI, the links are now broken, I suspect they have discontinued this feature.

Comment: URLs are broken

Comment: "Page not found"

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform

Answer (score 4):

Yes they do and it’s called the Commerce Platform.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/commerce-platform

Just click on that link to see they have an on boarding process that ultimately leads to listing items on Facebook marketplace.

More specifically, you will want to use the [Catalog Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog-batch) to add products via API calls.

Comment: Is this for marketplace? Can we share the image to fb marketplace directly from our iOS app?

Comment: sorry I don’t know you’ll have to check